# Running multiple Gstreamer Pipelines

Tags: multithreading, gstreamer

I am looking for an approach to fetch frames from Multiple v4l2 cameras using gstreamer at the best possible framerate . Would initiating multiple gstreamer pipelines using different threads created using pthread library work? Through command line running many pipelines results in fps drop . Would multithreading on a gpu have any effect on the fps stability ?